# Counting Deployments in DataDog

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, datadog

I have a Kubernetes cluster monitored by DataDog. I use the native integration and have all of the Kubernetes metrics. I also have APM. While I get the `time_between_deployments` metric and have `version` tracking with the `version` tag, I don't seem to have a good way to count the number of deployments I've made.

I also checked `Events` and don't get any good candidates for doing this with native Kubernetes Events either. CircleCI (which I also use) has an integration but it also doesn't provide Events.

My current thought is to write a script in my build pipeline that publishes an Event when a deployment is made. But before I do that I want to post here and make sure I'm not overlooking a simpler way to get this data.

**How can I get a count of unique deployments across my services in DataDog?**

Answer (score 0):

you could leverage the `kubernetes_state.deployment.count` metric.